# Switch between Feed and Details view button is missing

Tags: salesforce-classic, casefeed, service-console, feed-based-layout

I'm missing following **Switch between Feed and Details View** button on Case in Salesforce Classic Console. How can I add it to the Case Page Layout? The Feed-based-layout checkbox on Case Page Layout is checked.

[image: Switch between Feed and Details View]

Comment: Make sure you have access to the Chatter feature and related permissions on profile and case feed is Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions